# Background header moving along with the scrollbar

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, background-image

I have the issue of my background moving along with the scrollbar.That is, **the header of the page scrolls along with the scrollbar**. I have attached my code and the screenshot.Please help me...Thanks in advance.

My code:

```
  body.hixBodyBackground {
overflow:scroll;
        margin: 0px;
            background: url(../images/common/header/Background_color.png);
             background-repeat:repeat-x;
             background-attachment:fixed;
            background-position:top center;  
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            border: 0;
            background-size:contain;
            filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='../../KY/images/common/header/Background_color.png', sizingMethod='scale')";
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='../../KY/images/common/header/Background_color.png', sizingMethod='scale')";

body, html{
    height:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
      overflow-y: hidden;}
```

I have attached the screenshot.

Without scrolling:[image]

While scrolling:[image]

Answer (score 0):

Adding `overflow:scroll` to your CSS will fix the problem. In principle a cross-browser solution.

Answer (score 0):

it's better to change background: url(../images/common/header/Background_color.png); on background-image: url(../images/common/header/Background_color.png);